# Does sending goroutine get blocked?

Tags: go

I've created the example here: https://play.golang.org/p/kpV3T1XF9bz

Essentially, I have the main goroutine that creates three additiona goroutines.  In the main goroutine, I have a for loop with a `select` statement that prints the results of the created channel, followed by a sleep.

When I run the program, I don't see a delay in any of my print statements.  Does this mean that sending goroutines never block?

My expectation was that while the main goroutine was sleeping, before we looped back to the `select` statement, the unbuffered channel would not be ready to accept new data, but what I'm seeing contradicts this.

EDIT: Updated playground link with proper delay in seconds.

Comment: Sending operations block when they are blocked, and you are blocking these but only for a very short amount of time. `5 % time.Second` == `5ns`, I assume you meant `5 * time.Second`.

Comment: BTW, there's no reason for a `select` with a single `case` and looping over a single channel can be done with `for output := range c {`

Comment: Well I'll be, thanks for the catch.  Looks like things are working as expected.  Here's an updated link: https://play.golang.org/p/kpV3T1XF9bz.  It looks like the sender is blocked?  Ordering of output seems to be in random order.

Comment: Yes, they are blocked, because that is how channels are designed to work, -- they offer synchronization of the sender and receiver. The output order is random, because the goroutines are concurrent and there is no ordering imposed by the code.

Comment: Yes, a sending goroutine is blocked until the main goroutine is ready to receive. I don't see anything in the output that contradicts this.  Questions should include the relevant code inline.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use `select`. Just use the `for loop`, it will solve your problem. Here is the code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func First(c chan string) {
    c <- "FirstOne"
    // fmt.Println("First string")
}

func Second(c chan string) {
    c <- "SecondOne"
    // fmt.Println("Second string")
}

func Third(c chan string) {
    c <- "ThirdOne"
    // fmt.Println("Third string")
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    go First(c)
    go Second(c)
    go Third(c)

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    }
    fmt.Println("Timeout")
}
```